# Meteor User update calls router

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm calling update on Meteor.users client side to update the profile and I noticed it hits the Router after the update. I understand that Meteor.user() is reactive, and since I'm updating it, Meteor will update accordingly. But I guess I'm not sure why it's hitting the router, especially when I'm not getting any of the user's data on that page. Here's my update:

```
Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(), {$addToSet: {'profile.collection': @id}})
```

Complete routes code

```
Meteor.startup ->
  Session.setDefault 'subpage', ''

Router.configure
  layoutTemplate: "layout"
  loadingTemplate: "loading"

Router.before ->
  routeName = @route.name
  if Meteor.user() or Meteor.loggingIn()
    if _.include(["index"], routeName) then Router.go('collection')
    Session.set 'currentPage', routeName
  else
    if routeName isnt 'index' then Router.go 'index'


Router.map ->
  @route "index",
    path: "/"
  @route "collection"
  @route "discover"
  @route "playlists"
  @route "playlist",
    path: "/playlists/:_id"
    data: ->
      # Playlists.findOne(@params._id)
```

Comment: If you are using iron-router, some of the hooks are reactive. Please add the route code for a more complete answer.

Comment: Is it simply because I'm calling Meteor.user() in the before hook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't clearly documented, but iron router's `before` hook is reactive. Usually this is what you want, but I can see how this would be annoying if you updated the user's profile. I think an easy solution is to look for `Meteor.userId()` instead of `Meteor.user()`. This accomplishes the same thing but the id won't change when the user's profile is updated.